# matrixTransform on svg: unexpected behaviour

Tags: javascript, svg, transform, perspective

I have a div containing an SVG image of 300x300 px and a viewbox of 1000x1000.
The image describes a blue rectangle on top of a red one.
When I move the mouse a circle is following the mouse position inside the image:

[image]

Everything is perfect except that when I apply a transformation changing perspective and rotation, the mouse pointer and circle center are not anymore matching:

[image]

Code is here:

```js
$(function() {
 $('#image').mousemove(function(event) {
  var svg = document.querySelector('svg');
  var pt = svg.createSVGPoint();
  pt.x = event.clientX;
  pt.y = event.clientY;
  pt = pt.matrixTransform(svg.getScreenCTM().inverse());
  overlay = document.getElementById('overlay');
  $('#overlay').html(
   "<circle cx='" + pt.x + "' cy='" + pt.y + "' r='50' stroke='#8f00ff' fill='transparent' stroke-width='10' /></svg>"
  );
  refresh = $("#overlay").html();
  $("#overlay").html( refresh )
 });
});
function Transform() {
 $('#image').css({
  transformOrigin: '500px 500px',
  transform: 'perspective(100px) rotateX(5deg)'
 });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='image' tabindex='0' >
 <svg id='svgmap' width='300' height='300' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' version='1.1' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' viewBox='0 0 1000 1000'>
  <rect x='0' y='0' width='1000' height='1000' fill='red' />
  <rect x='250' y='250' width='500' height='500' stroke='yellow' fill='blue' stroke-width='10' />
  <g id='overlay'></g>
 </svg>
</div>
<button onclick='Transform()'>Transform</button>
```

My goal is to preserver matching between the purple circle center and the mouse pointer, even when a transformation is applied to the object.
Is there a way to do it?

Comment: you'd have to calculate the transform yourself. Browsers implementations of getScreenCTM have bugs when presented with CSS transforms.

Comment: @Robert Longson Hi Robert. All browsers have bugs or only with Cromium core?

Comment: Chrome does not support 3D transforms of SVG at all. You're actually transforming the parent div there. But yes, 3D transforms of SVG have issues in all browsers.

Comment: @Stefano Radaelli Hi. The solution is right for you if the circle is not transformed?

Comment: @AlexanderV.Ulyanov yes it could. I would have to adapt it but it would be anyway ok. Are you suggesting me to draw circle on a top layer not impacted by any transformation? This is an alternative option that I'm currently evaluating with application customer.

Comment: @Stefano Radaelli :-) Yes. You can also try drawing squares without transformation using a <path/>.

Comment: @Stefano Radaelli i mean using <path/> instead <rect/>.

Answer (score 3):

In your code `#image` is a div. In order to make it work you need to apply the transformation to the svg element (#svgmap) and the transformation must be an svg transformation.

```js
$(function() {
 $('#svgmap').mousemove(function(event) {
  var svg = document.querySelector('svg');
  var pt = svg.createSVGPoint();
  pt.x = event.clientX;
  pt.y = event.clientY;
  pt = pt.matrixTransform(svg.getScreenCTM().inverse());
  overlay = document.getElementById('overlay');
  $('#overlay').html(
   "<circle cx='" + pt.x + "' cy='" + pt.y + "' r='50' stroke='#8f00ff' fill='transparent' stroke-width='10' /></svg>"
  );
  refresh = $("#layer_wafer").html();
  $("#layer_wafer").html( refresh )
 });
});
function Transform() {
 svgmap.setAttributeNS(null,"transform", "skewX(-20) translate(100)");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='image' tabindex='0' >
 <svg id='svgmap' width='300' height='300' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' version='1.1' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' viewBox='0 0 1000 1000' transform="">
  <rect x='0' y='0' width='1000' height='1000' fill='red' />
    
  <rect x='250' y='250' width='500' height='500' stroke='yellow' fill='blue' stroke-width='10' />
  <g id='overlay'></g>
 </svg>
</div>
<button onclick='Transform()'>Transform</button>
```

I understand that you are needing a 3D css transformation but this (at least for now) doesn't work.

This is an article where you can read more about 3d transforms in svg:  https://oreillymedia.github.io/Using_SVG/extras/ch11-3d.html In the article you can read: *All the 3D transformation functions described in this section should be considered “future”*

Comment: 3D transformations of SVG content work in Firefox for display, we don't currently calculate the getScreenCTM correctly.

Comment: @enxaneta This is really a very difficult 3D topic to learn. Thanks for the reply and link.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Very clear. Maybe I hadn't been clear enought as the problem that I have is not to apply a transformation on a DIV instead that on an SVG element. The problem that I have is that (in case of perpective transformation applied), the purple circle does not match anymore with mouse position. Most probably and as suggested by @Robert Longson, I have to work on getScreentCTM function to understand something more. The posted code works perfectly with Chrome (and being part of a standalone application, I can force the user to not use any other different browser).

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the issue in the ugliest possible way. Simply hiding the mouse cursor over the div.
Ugly. But effective.

```js
$(function() {
 $('#image').mousemove(function(event) {
  var svg = document.querySelector('svg');
  var pt = svg.createSVGPoint();
  pt.x = event.clientX;
  pt.y = event.clientY;
  pt = pt.matrixTransform(svg.getScreenCTM().inverse());
  overlay = document.getElementById('overlay');
  $('#overlay').html(
   "<circle cx='" + pt.x + "' cy='" + pt.y + "' r='50' stroke='#8f00ff' fill='transparent' stroke-width='10' /></svg>"
  );
  refresh = $("#overlay").html();
  $("#overlay").html( refresh )
 });
});
function Transform() {
 $('#image').css({
  transformOrigin: '500px 500px',
  transform: 'perspective(100px) rotateX(5deg)'
 });
}
```

```css
div#image {
  cursor: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='image' tabindex='0' >
 <svg id='svgmap' width='300' height='300' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' version='1.1' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' viewBox='0 0 1000 1000'>
  <rect x='0' y='0' width='1000' height='1000' fill='red' />
  <rect x='250' y='250' width='500' height='500' stroke='yellow' fill='blue' stroke-width='10' />
  <g id='overlay'></g>
 </svg>
</div>
<button onclick='Transform()'>Transform</button>
```

There's a little bit of optimization that I have to do to reduce the mouse cursor position gap between the DIV over and any other page element, but it's acceptable to me.